# Problems obfuscating Android application that uses Spring for Android

Tags: android, spring, proguard

I'm using Spring for Android in my application, and I'm trying to obfuscate/optimize/shrink using Proguard. I'm getting the following exception at runtime:

> Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could
>   not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request
>   type [com.mycompany.myproduct.AuthenticateRequest] and content type
>   [application/json]
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:610)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:449)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:414)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:390)

I'm guessing there's some things I need to `-keep` in my proguard.cfg file, but I can't seem to figure out what they might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my proguard.cfg file I added the following, and it did the trick:

```
-keep class org.springframework.** { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.jackson.** { *; }
```